# Flutter - Limit width of application to biggest phone

Tags: flutter

We have a phone application and wish to release to tablets as well, but we want to limit the app on tablet to look like on a biggest phone. Just width would be fine.

Is there an option to limit the screen size for the entire app?
Also, when I call MediaQuery size.width is that dpi or pixels or what?

It seems to me that I would have to go to everyscreen and put them in a container with max width but I was interested in other options.

This is all for Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit your app to fixed max width, you could simply wrap the material app inside container with fixed max width.

Example

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 700),
        child: GetMaterialApp(
                title: "Fixed width app"
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```